# How to include a script into my build folder separately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that requires a background script (background.js). Currently when I npm run build, the project is built as normal in the build folder. I then copy and paste background.js into the build folder, and this works perfectly.

What I want is for this script to be automatically included in my build folder when I npm run build my project. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the script to the `public` folder and add this line to your `index.html` file:

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/background.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eject your app:

```
npm run eject
```

and then in package.json under scripts change:

```
"build": "node scripts/build.js
```

to

```
"build": "node scripts/build.js && cp background.js build/background.js"
```