# Importing 3rd party javascript asset

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to import a 3rd party javascript asset into a ReactJS project.  I'm relatively new to React and haven't a need to do this until now (usually everything I need is a npm package and placed in node_modules, however this file does not have an npm package).

I have placed the 3rd party javascript into the `/assets/scripts` directory, but when I try to import it gives me and error about `You attempted to import <file> which falls outside of the project src/ directory.` error when compiling.

Is there a reliable way to import a 3rd party javascript file (and supporting css files) within a ReactJS project?

Thanks again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a script into my build folder separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635815/how-to-include-a-script-into-my-build-folder-separately)

Comment: Throlle's answer was the correct answer for my solution.